# Can't get name, email and picture from Facebook integration with Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to integrate Facebook as a login in my navigation drawer app and when I click on Facebook button I can login but after login the app doesn't show me the name, email and picture.

I have already try differents ways to get name, email and picture but it doesn't work. One of those ways was to put `Profile profileDefault = Profile.getCurrentProfile()` in "On Sucess" and then profileDefault.getFirstName() but when I run the app and after the login the app stop.

When I use the function `getFaceBookProfileDetails` I can login and after that the app keeps run but doesn't show me the name,email and picture.

This is the Main Activity

```
package com.example.abdiel.culi;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import static android.view.View.INVISIBLE;
import static com.example.abdiel.culi.R.id.imageviewFotoPerfil;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
   // private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
   // private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    LoginButton buttonLoginFacebook;
    TextView textViewName, textViewEmail;
    ImageView imageViewPhoto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewNombre);
        buttonLoginFacebook = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewEmail);
        buttonLoginFacebook.setReadPermissions("email");
        imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewFotoPerfil);


        buttonLoginFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                //Método usado para obtener los campos o atributos solciitados
                 getFaceBookProfileDetails(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                //buttonLoginFacebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    private void getFaceBookProfileDetails(final AccessToken accessToken) {

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
               try {
                    //Profile clase que contiene las características báscias de la cuenta de facebook (No retorna email)
                    Profile profileDefault = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    //Librería usada para poder mostrar la foto de perfil de facebook con una transformación circular
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(profileDefault.getProfilePictureUri(100,100)).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imageViewPhoto);
                    textViewName.setText(profileDefault.getFirstName());
                    textViewEmail.setText(object.getString("email"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("E-MainActivity", "getFaceBook" + e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        //solicitando el campo email
        parameters.putString("fields",   "email");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Retorna la reppuesta después del ingreso de las credenciales de facebook
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.itemBusqueda) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abdiel.culi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider442630429253125"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity android:name=".Recomendados_Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the Build Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abdiel.culi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the Content Main XML of the navigation drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.abdiel.culi.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the activity main XML of the navigation drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I also tried this code following the steps of the answers but when I run the app it stops.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
   // private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    Profile profile;
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

    LoginButton buttonLoginFacebook;
    TextView textViewName, textViewEmail;
    ImageView imageViewPhoto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
                updateWithToken(newToken);
            }
        };
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();

        buttonLoginFacebook = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        buttonLoginFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
        //buttonLoginFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager,callback);
        buttonLoginFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        try {
                            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                                mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile_old, Profile profile_new) {
                                        // profile2 is the new profile
                                        profile = profile_new;
                                        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                                    }
                                };
                                mProfileTracker.startTracking();
                            } else {
                                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                Log.v("facebook - profile", profile.getFirstName());
                            }

                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                            Log.v("FACEBOOK LOGIN", response.toString());
                                            // Application code
                                            try {
                                                //Profile clase que contiene las características báscias de la cuenta de facebook (No retorna email)
                                                Profile profileDefault = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                                //Librería usada para poder mostrar la foto de perfil de facebook con una transformación circular
                                                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(profileDefault.getProfilePictureUri(100,100)).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imageViewPhoto);
                                                textViewName.setText(profileDefault.getFirstName());
                                                textViewEmail.setText(object.getString("email"));
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                            //show facebook data in your activity
                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "name,email,picture");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK ERRROR", e.toString());

                    }
                });




        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewNombre);

        textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewEmail);

        imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewFotoPerfil);




        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



    private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

        if (currentAccessToken != null) {
            //User logged In--do your stuff
            //log out user first
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        } else {
            //user not logged in
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Retorna la reppuesta después del ingreso de las credenciales de facebook
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.itemBusqueda) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one `manageCallBackOfFacebook()` method or directly put callback code in you activity. Handle your facebook callback in you activity class.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //initialize facebook Sdk
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        manageCallBackOfFacebook();
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView();
        ...
    }

    private void manageCallBackOfFacebook()
    {
        try
        {
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

                }
            };

            profileTracker = new ProfileTracker()
            {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile)
                {
                    if (newProfile != null)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG +" getName ", newProfile.getName());""+newProfile.getLinkUri());
                        Log.i(TAG +" getProfilePictureUri", ""+newProfile.getProfilePictureUri(200, 150));
                    }
                }
            };

            accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
            profileTracker.startTracking();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the method manageCallBackOfFacebook()? Should I put it into "On create" or into "On success". Please be more specific step by step. Look at my code and  if you can show me the entire code of Main Activity I will be apreciate it.  Im new in android studio . Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work. The app stops when I click on Facebook Button. I followed your steps and nothing. Any suggestion? I need to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes..

Declare

```
Profile profile;
private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
```

In your onCreate()

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
            updateWithToken(newToken);
        }
    };
    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();

   loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
   loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
            "public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
```

in your updateWithToken() method

```
    private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

    if (currentAccessToken != null) {
        //User logged In--do your stuff
        //log out user first
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    } else {
        //user not logged in
      }
   }
```

Also in your callback method -add this into activity

```
 private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        try {
            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile_old, Profile profile_new) {
                        // profile2 is the new profile
                        profile = profile_new;
                        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                    }
                };
                mProfileTracker.startTracking();
            } else {
                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                Log.v("facebook - profile", profile.getFirstName());
            }

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("FACEBOOK LOGIN", response.toString());
                            // Application code
                            try {
                                fb_id = object.getString("id");
                                fb_name = object.getString("name");
                                profilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
                                fb_email = object.getString("email");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            //show facebook data in your activity
                         }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.type(small)");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.d("FACEBOOK ERRROR", e.toString());
    }
};
```

Comment: I just do that and when I run  the app it stops. It doesn't even start the app.

Comment: 12-20 02:56:23.693 14853-14883/? D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x518071a0 sslRead buf=0x4153c9c8 len=1,timeo=0
12-20 02:56:23.693 14853-14883/? D/NativeCrypto: Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x518071a0, appData=0x50190d80
12-20 02:56:23.693 14853-14883/? D/NativeCrypto: Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x518071a0, appData=0x50190d80

Comment: Can you help me to find out the problem please. Look at my code, maybe something is wrong.